# Load pentaho Log to a field

Tags: logging, pentaho

Pentaho db loggging option has to load log of particular transformation to a field called LOG_FIELD.

I'm trying to create a custom table, where I wanted to load the log to a field. How to extract and load the log at each transformation level??

Comment: Please tell us the fields you want to log.

Comment: Are you talking about logging the pentaho BI server, or the PDI ?

Comment: Are you familiar with java programming ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click anywhere on the the transformation you want to log, and select `Properties...` of the drop down menu.
2. Select the `Logging` tab.
3. On the left select `Transformation` (Easy to forget).
4. Define the database connection and a table name (preferably an non-exiting table).
5. Select the fields you want to log.

   - Specify the step to be used to count the LINES_READ, LINES_WRITTEN,...
   - Do not uncheck the LOG_FIELD which is the one you are looking for.
   - Caution: the START_DATE is not what you think, the time at which the run started is called the RELAY_DATE. The misnamed START_DATE is the date of the last run of the same transformation, used for incremental update.
6. Set a logging interval (example 2 sec), in case you want to follow the run from the database.
7. Press the SQL button to create the table.

That's all. When you run the transformation, the selected fields will be written on the database.

**Note:** If you want to do this systematically for all transformations, edit the `kettle.poroperties` (top menu `Edit`) and define the variables KETTLE_TRANS_LOG_DB and KETTLE_TRANS_LOG_TABLE once for all. And remember, the kettle.properties may be different on your dev machine and your prod server.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer..   hope I was not clear at asking. I would like to create a custom table not the existing log table. so how can I do that because there are certain fields need to be added in the custom table like Source system details in order to know which source system I'm processing for...   I don;t think I can edit existing settings of pentaho DB logging

Comment: The answer may talk a lot of question/answers.

Comment: You have a step called `Write to log` which allows you to write the System details (from the `Get system info` step) in the LOG_FIELD

Comment: The db loggings are sql tables like any other. It means that you can write in them with the PDI. You can also read the LOG_FIELD from this table and write it to your own logging.